# Linked list error: 'int' object has no attribute 'next'

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list

I am just getting started with data structures here. I am trying to implement linked list with python. But keep getting an error! I will really appreciate your insight. Here is my code,

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None


class LinkedList(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = Node()

    def append(self, new_element):
        current = self.head
        if self.head:
            while current.next:             #line 14
                current = current.next
            current.next = new_element
        else:
            self.head = new_element

    def length(self):
        count = 0
        current = self.head
        if self.head:
            while current.next:
                count += count
                current = current.next
            return count
        else:
            return count

    def display(self):
        elements = []
        current = self.head
        if self.head:
            while current.next:
                elements.append(current)
                current = current.next
            print(elements)
        else:
            print(elements)


my_list = LinkedList()
my_list.append(1)
my_list.append(2) #line 45
my_list.append(3)
my_list.append(4)
my_list.append(5)
my_list.length()
my_list.display()
```

This is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Desktop/ds/linkedlist.py", line 45, in <module>
    my_list.append(2)
  File "C:/Users/Desktop/ds/linkedlist.py", line 14, in append
    while current.next is not None:
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'next'
```

I am having the same error for all my methods, i.e. append, length and display in the `LinkedList` class. Is the error saying `current` is an int?

Answer (score 0):

You are appending `int` elements (instead of `Node`s) to the list as your `append` method is designed for `Nodes` (as `next_element`) but you are passing `int`s.

Instead do the following:

`my_list.append(Node(1))`

It´s even better to adjust your `append` method the following way, so you can add arbitrary elements without creating `Nodes` manually.

```
 def append(self, new_element):
        node = Node(new_element)
        current = self.head
        if self.head:
            while current.next:             #line 14
                current = current.next
            current.next = node
        else:
            self.head = node
```

To display not the `Node`s (which are objects, so you see memory locations) but their values you have to adjust one line in your `display` method:

`elements.append(current.data)`

Comment: I am getting memory addresses when I do that! also, how do I write the code so I don't have to write Node(1)?

Comment: see my modified answer

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed response!! One last question, when I test the code like this

```my_list = LinkedList()```
```my_list.append(100)```
```my_list.append(1)```
```my_list.append(2)```
```my_list.append(3)```
```my_list.append(4)```
```my_list.append(5)```
```my_list.display()```

This is what I get,
```[None, 100, 1, 2, 3, 4]```

Why am I getting None at index 0?

Comment: The reason is your list constructor `LinkedList()`, which creates the first Node without any data. Replace the list init with the following:
`def __init__(self, value):`

`self.head = Node(value)`

Comment: Of course you have to use this as well: `my_list = LinkedList(0)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should at a list in the innit part because what you are doing in the append function is basically update the head variable so basically it is not a list so you cannot use the next method on that variable